# Replace "\x" with "0x" in a text using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text that contains `\x` and I want to replace this pair with `0x`. I used the below Python commands, but all failed:

```
>>> text= '\x1bs\x1b\x01Z\xa2\x8d\xa2^\xb9*d\x08\x10&B\xb1z\xd4\xa91\xa3D
\xaf\xa1\x9a\x94\x8c\xd3\xb2r\x80\xc3\xb7)\xd8\x1bi\x80\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10@
\x81}0\xa8J\x95\x02E\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10@
\x9f+\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x02^\xd3Q\xcc\xd70\x0eB\x88A\x1chB\x1bL\x81\xadC\x00
\x84!\rr(\x07\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x03
\x00?\x1c\x1b0'
>>>
>>>
>>> text.replace('\x',' 0x')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
>>>
>>>
>>> text.replace(u'\x',' 0x')
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
>>>
>>>
>>> text.replace(r'\x',' 0x')
'\x1bs\x1b\x01Z¢\x8d¢^¹*d\x08\x10&B±zÔ©1£D¯¡\x9a\x94\x8cÓ²r\x80Ã·)Ø\x1bi\x80
\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81}0¨J\x95\x02E\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81
\x02\x04\x08\x10@\x9f+\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x02^ÓQÌ×0\x0eB\x88A\x1chB\x1bL\x81\xadC
\x00\x84!\rr(\x07ÿ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x03
\x00?\x1c\x1b0'
>>>
>>>
>>> text.replace('\\x',' 0x')
'\x1bs\x1b\x01Z¢\x8d¢^¹*d\x08\x10&B±zÔ©1£D¯¡\x9a\x94\x8cÓ²r\x80Ã·)Ø\x1bi\x80
\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81}0¨J\x95\x02E\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81
\x02\x04\x08\x10@\x9f+\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x02^ÓQÌ×0\x0eB\x88A\x1chB\x1bL\x81\xadC
\x00\x84!\rr(\x07ÿ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x03
\x00?\x1c\x1b0'
>>>
```

What's wrong? What shall I do?

*Note that I am using Python 3.4.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that the text **does not** contain `\x`. See the linked duplicate to understand how to make it contain what you thought it contained, and also more generally to understand what the string literal currently means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
text= repr('''\x1bs\x1b\x01Z\xa2\x8d\xa2^\xb9*d\x08\x10&B\xb1z\xd4\xa91\xa3D
\xaf\xa1\x9a\x94\x8c\xd3\xb2r\x80\xc3\xb7)\xd8\x1bi\x80\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10@
\x81}0\xa8J\x95\x02E\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10 @\x81\x02\x04\x08\x10@
\x9f+\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x02^\xd3Q\xcc\xd70\x0eB\x88A\x1chB\x1bL\x81\xadC\x00
\x84!\rr(\x07\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x03
\x00?\x1c\x1b0''')

print text.replace("\\x","0x")
```

Use representation of the original string and then replace

Comment: Nice practical solution, but why is this necessary? Why don't any of the OP's approaches work?

Comment: Will work unless the original string has a real `r'\x'` sequence somewhere.

Comment: @Kevin The leading \x escape sequence means the next two characters are interpreted as hex digits. so using \x alone will throw error. I think string.replace() will search and replace whole character here \x itself is not a string \x00 will be considered a character

Comment: @k4vin: maybe it's a lack of commas, but I couldn't understand this: `will search and replace whole character here \x itself is not a string \x00 will be considered a character`. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @bad_keypoints if you have a variable `text= "\t"` you can replace tab by `text.replace("\t","0x")` here `"\t"` is considered a whole character if you try to do `text.replace("\\t","0x")` it won't replace anything.